# PostgreSQL - Filling values in a column based on another column

Tags: postgresql

an extract of my dataset looks like this :

```
|time_1      | status | statut_2y |
|            |        |           |
|2017-01-01  |    X   |           | 
|2017-02-01  |    X   |           |  
|2017-03-01  |    X   |           | 
|2017-04-01  |    X   |           | 
|2017-05-01  |    X   |           |
|2017-06-01  |    X   |           |
|2017-07-01  |    X   |           |
|2017-08-01  |    X   |           |
|2019-01-01  |    0   |           | 
|2019-02-01  |    1   |           | 
|2019-03-01  |    0   |           | 
|2019-04-01  |    0   |           | 
|2019-05-01  |    1   |           | 
|2019-06-01  |    1   |           | 
|2019-07-01  |    0   |           | 
|2019-08-01  |    1   |           |
```

So basically what I want in the column **statut_2y** is to put the status equivalent after 2 years.

For example :
For 2017-01-01 : we'll have the value **0** because in 2019-01-01 the status = 0.

I hope I was clear enough.. (English isn't my first language)

Thanks!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You need to self-join to make this happen:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET status_2y = self.status
FROM table AS self
WHERE self.time_1 = table.time_1 + '2 YEARS'::interval
```